# Bluetooth SPP from Adobe Actionscript (Flex Framework), how?

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash, bluetooth

I am successfully running Bluetooth-SPP applications relying on http://bluecove.org/
That is Java to Java.
I do now want to establish Bluetooth-connectivity in an Adobe Flex-application. Anyone has experience, ideas? 
I appreciate your advise.
Thank you
Bart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you would pull this off in Flex.

For an AIR app, you should have a look at Merapi which is a AIR to java bridge. I haven't yet used it personally though.

[Merapi Project link](http://www.merapiproject.net/)

hth

Koen

Answer (score 0):

You will have to communicate via some sort of proxy. Create your proxy in java and make it listen on a port that flash/flex connects to -- you can use http requests, but it might be more fitting to use an [xml socket](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html).

Koen Weyn's suggestion of [Merapi](http://www.merapiproject.net/index.php) looks like a good one if you don't want to build it yourself (I've also never used it).